# Online Hebrew Letter Maker

Tags: product-recommendation, aleph-bet-letters

I'm looking for an online tool which will allow me to produce a Hebrew word in the K'tav Ashuri, Torah font.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Oyvay. Hope to see you around!

Comment: Note there are lots of versions of Ktav Ashuri, so if you have a specific need you should clarify. Arguably, most standard Hebrew fonts out there are kosher ktav ashuri

Comment: I think MS Word / Office has a few built in. But, as @ezra stated, there are various sites from where you can download free fonts. Fonts become part of Windows, not specifically Word or other software. So, once installed, they should work for any software you use.

Answer (score 7):

<strike>There is no online tool that I know of</strike> (See [aBochur's answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/91996/11486)) <strike>but</strike> you can download an Ashuri font and produce the word yourself in a word processor. See [here](https://opensiddur.org/help/fonts/) for a collection of great fonts, some of which are Ashuri. I personally have downloaded all of these fonts and use them regularly; it's a great font pack.

Answer (score 5):

[Here's an online tool](https://www.fonts.com/font/masterfont/torah/regular)
that allows you to write a word in Hebrew, and it will then convert it into ktav ashuri.

The downside is, that you cannot copy the word as is, you can only save it as an image.

[image]